# SetInterval/Slider is not working with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a Circular Content Carousel from codrops, with some modifications.

I'm trying to make the slider autoscroll with setInterval call. In IE and Firefoxe it works fine, but in Chrome it only slides once and never more. Can anyone check what is wrong with my setInterval code?

Here is the piece of code I'm using for the auto scroll:

```
var autoscroll = setInterval(function() {
    aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
},5000);
```

I need to call the aux.navigate with the variables given, its one way of making the slider scroll forever.

Here is the full code of the Slider with my modifications (the auto scroll piece of code is near the end, in the end of the methodes part):

```
(function($) {

var aux     = {

        // navigates left / right
        navigate    : function( dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache ) {

            var scroll      = opts.scroll,
                factor      = 1,
                idxClicked  = 0;

            if( cache.expanded ) {
                scroll      = 1; // scroll is always 1 in full mode
                factor      = 3; // the width of the expanded item will be 3 times bigger than 1 collapsed item 
                idxClicked  = cache.idxClicked; // the index of the clicked item
            }

            // clone the elements on the right / left and append / prepend them according to dir and scroll
            if( dir === 1 ) {
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:lt(' + scroll + ')').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', ( cache.totalItems - idxClicked + i ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).appendTo( $wrapper );
                });
            }
            else {
                var $first  = $wrapper.children().eq(0);

                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:gt(' + ( cache.totalItems  - 1 - scroll ) + ')').each(function(i) {
                    // insert before $first so they stay in the right order
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', - ( scroll - i + idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).insertBefore( $first );
                });
            }

            // animate the left of each item
            // the calculations are dependent on dir and on the cache.expanded value
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this);
                $item.stop().animate({
                    left    :  ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px' : '+=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px'
                }, opts.sliderSpeed, opts.sliderEasing, function() {
                    if( ( dir === 1 && $item.position().left < - idxClicked * cache.itemW * factor ) || ( dir === -1 && $item.position().left > ( ( cache.totalItems - 1 - idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor ) ) ) {
                        // remove the item that was cloned
                        $item.remove();
                    }                       
                    cache.isAnimating   = false;
                });
            });

        },
        // opens an item (animation) -> opens all the others
        openItem    : function( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache ) {
            cache.idxClicked    = $item.index();
            // the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items) 
            cache.winpos        = aux.getWinPos( $item.position().left, cache );


            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').not( $item ).hide();

            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item-main').hide();

            //$item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').stop().animate({ sera a solução para nao haver espaço branco ao fim do scroll em fullscreen??
            $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css( 'left', cache.itemW + 'px' ).stop().animate({
                width   : cache.itemW * 3 + 'px',
                left    : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
            .end()
            .stop()
            .animate({
                left    : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating   = false;
                cache.expanded      = true;

                aux.openItems( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache );
            });

        },
        // opens all the items
        openItems   : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this),
                    idx     = $item.index();

                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.css( 'left', - ( openedIdx - idx ) * ( cache.itemW * 3 ) + 'px' ).show().find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        left    : '0px',
                        width   : cache.itemW * 3 + 'px'
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        // close all the items
        // the current one is animated
        closeItems  : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

            $openedItem.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').stop().animate({
                width   : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
            .end()
            .stop()
            .animate({
                left    : cache.itemW * ( cache.winpos - 1 ) + 'px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating   = false;
                cache.expanded      = false;
            });

            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this),
                    idx     = $item.index();

                $item.find('div.ca-item-main').show();

                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        width   : '0px'
                    })
                    .end()
                    .css( 'left', ( ( cache.winpos - 1 ) - ( openedIdx - idx ) ) * cache.itemW + 'px' )
                    .show();
                }
            });
        },
        // gets the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items)
        // val is the left of the item
        getWinPos   : function( val, cache ) {
            switch( val ) {
                case 0                  : return 1; break;
                case cache.itemW        : return 2; break;
                case cache.itemW * 2    : return 3; break;
            }
        }
    },
    methods = {
        init        : function( options ) {

            if( this.length ) {

                var settings = {
                    sliderSpeed     : 500,          // speed for the sliding animation
                    sliderEasing    : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the sliding animation
                    itemSpeed       : 500,          // speed for the item animation (open / close)
                    itemEasing      : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the item animation (open / close)
                    scroll          : 1             // number of items to scroll at a time
                };

                return this.each(function() {

                    // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    var $el             = $(this),
                        $wrapper        = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),
                        $items          = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),
                        cache           = {};

                    // save the with of one item    
                    cache.itemW         = $items.width();
                    // save the number of total items
                    cache.totalItems    = $items.length;

                    // add navigation buttons
                    if( cache.totalItems > 3 )  
                        $el.prepend('<div class="ca-nav"><span class="ca-nav-prev">Previous</span><span class="ca-nav-next">Next</span></div>') 

                    // control the scroll value
                    if( settings.scroll < 1 )
                        settings.scroll = 1;
                    else if( settings.scroll > 3 )
                        settings.scroll = 3;    

                    var $navPrev        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-prev'),
                        $navNext        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-next');

                    // hide the items except the first 3
                    $wrapper.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );

                    // the items will have position absolute 
                    // calculate the left of each item
                    $items.each(function(i) {
                        $(this).css({
                            position    : 'absolute',
                            left        : i * cache.itemW + 'px'
                        });
                    });

                    // click to open the item(s)
                    $el.find('a.ca-more').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.openItem( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        return false;
                    });

                    // click to close the item(s)
                    $el.find('a.ca-close').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.closeItems( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        return false;
                    });

                    // navigate left
                    $navPrev.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });

                    // navigate right
                    $navNext.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });

                    // adds events to the mouse
                    $el.bind('mousewheel.contentcarousel', function(e, delta) {
                        if(delta > 0) {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        else {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        return false;
                    });


                    var autoscroll = setInterval(function() {
                    aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    },1000);

                });
            }
        }
    };

$.fn.contentcarousel = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.contentcarousel' );
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

I have tried a lot of combintions of code, searched a lot, but can't make it to work on Chrome, in other browsers it works fine. Thanks a lot for any teaching and helping about this.

**PS/EDIT:**

**I added the Slider to a temporary server, you can find it working online here with the full code: http://ceh.ilch.uminho.pt/test/**

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Does normal left/right navigation continue to work in Chrome?

Comment: In the console there are no errors unfortunately (i wish there were for guidance :/

Comment: In Chrome, everything works normal, and manually the scroll works good, but the auto scroll part is the strange part: it scrolls just once than nothing more happen. In IE and Firefox the auto scroll never stops and I can't find why :S

Comment: Added a temporary link to the slider working with the full code if it helps: http://ceh.ilch.uminho.pt/test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a particular reason why Chrome should have a problem (other than it's a common theme these days) however you could try triggering a click on the "next" button, to automatically look after `cache.isAnimating` :

```
var autoscroll = setInterval(function() {
    $navNext.trigger('click.contentcarousel');
}, 5000);
```

### EDIT

OK, after some serious tidying of the code and converting to work with jQuery 1.9.1 (previously jQuery 1.6.2), I ended up with this :

```
(function($) {
    var pluginName = 'contentcarousel';

    //Define event namespace strings
    var evt_ns = {
        click: 'click.' + pluginName,
        mousewheel: 'mousewheel.' + pluginName
    };
    var aux = {
        // navigates left / right
        navigate: function( dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache ) {
            if( cache.isAnimating ) return;
            cache.isAnimating = true;
            var scroll = ( cache.expanded ) ? 1 : opts.scroll,
                factor = ( cache.expanded ) ? 3 : 1,// expanded width will be 3x that of one collapsed item
                idxClicked = ( cache.expanded ) ? cache.idxClicked : 0;
            // clone the elements on the right / left and append / prepend them according to dir and scroll
            if( dir === 1 ) {
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:lt(' + scroll + ')').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', ( cache.totalItems - idxClicked + i ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).appendTo( $wrapper );
                });
            }
            else {
                var $first = $wrapper.children().eq(0);
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:gt(' + ( cache.totalItems  - 1 - scroll ) + ')').each(   function(i) {
                    // insert before $first so they stay in the right order
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', - ( scroll - i + idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).insertBefore( $first );
                });
            }
            // animate the left of each item
            // the calculations are dependent on dir and on the cache.expanded value
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item = $(this);
                $item.stop().animate({
                    left : ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px' : '+=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px'
                }, opts.sliderSpeed, opts.sliderEasing, function() {
                    if( ( dir === 1 && $item.position().left < - idxClicked * cache.itemW * factor ) || ( dir === -1 && $item.position().left > ( ( cache.totalItems - 1 - idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor ) ) ) {
                        // remove the item that was cloned
                        $item.remove();
                    }
                    cache.isAnimating = false;
                });
            });
        },
        // opens an item (animation) -> opens all the others
        openItem: function( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache ) {
            if( cache.isAnimating ) return;
            cache.isAnimating = true;
            cache.idxClicked = $item.index();
            // the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items) 
            cache.winpos = aux.getWinPos( $item.position().left, cache );
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').not( $item ).hide();
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item-main').hide();
            //$item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').stop().animate({ sera a solução para nao haver espaço branco ao fim do scroll em fullscreen??
            $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css( 'left', cache.itemW + 'px' ).stop().animate({
                left : '0px',
                width : cache.itemW * 3 + 'px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing).end().stop().animate({
                left : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating = false;
                cache.expanded = true;
                aux.openItems( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache );
            });
        },
        // opens all the items
        openItems: function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            var openedIdx = $openedItem.index();
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item = $(this),
                    idx = $item.index();
                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.css( 'left', - ( openedIdx - idx ) * ( cache.itemW * 3 ) + 'px' ).show().find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        left : '0px',
                        width : cache.itemW * 3 + 'px'
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        // close all the items
        // the current one is animated
        closeItems: function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            if( cache.isAnimating ) return;
            cache.isAnimating = true;
            var openedIdx = $openedItem.index();
            $openedItem.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').stop().animate({
                width: '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing).end().stop().animate({
                left: cache.itemW * ( cache.winpos - 1 ) + 'px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating = false;
                cache.expanded = false;
            });
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item = $(this),
                    idx = $item.index();
                $item.find('div.ca-item-main').show();
                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        width: '0px'
                    }).end().css( 'left', ( ( cache.winpos - 1 ) - ( openedIdx - idx ) ) * cache.itemW + 'px' ).show();
                }
            });
        },
        // gets the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items)
        // val is the left of the item
        getWinPos: function( val, cache ) {
            switch( val ) {
                case 0: return 1; break;
                case cache.itemW: return 2; break;
                case cache.itemW * 2: return 3; break;
            }
        },
        startAuto: function( dir, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache ) {
        aux.stopAuto( cache );
            aux.navigate( dir, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
            cache.autoscroll = setInterval(function() {
                aux.navigate( dir, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
            }, 1000);
        },
        stopAuto: function( cache ) {
            if(cache.autoscroll) {
                clearInterval(cache.autoscroll);
                cache.autoscroll = null;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    },
    methods = {
        init : function( options ) {
            if( this.length ) {
                var settings = {
                    autoStart: false,
                    sliderSpeed: 500, // speed for the sliding animation
                    sliderEasing: 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the sliding animation
                    itemSpeed: 500, // speed for the item animation (open / close)
                    itemEasing: 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the item animation (open / close)
                    scroll: 1 // number of items to scroll at a time
                };
                return this.each(function() {
                    // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }
                    // control the scroll value
                    settings.scroll = Math.max(Math.min(settings.scroll, 3), 1);
                    var $el = $(this),
                        $wrapper = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),
                        $items = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),
                        cache = {
                            autoscroll: null,
                            itemW: $items.width(),// save the width of one item
                            totalItems: $items.length// save the number of total items
                        };
                    // add navigation buttons
                    if( cache.totalItems > 3 )
                        $el.prepend('<div class="ca-nav"><span class="ca-nav-prev">Previous</span><span class="ca-nav-next">Next</span></div>');
                    var controls = {
                        navPrev: $el.find('span.ca-nav-prev'),
                        navNext: $el.find('span.ca-nav-next'),
                        more: $el.find('a.ca-more'),
                        close: $el.find('a.ca-close'),
                        auto: $el.find('a.ca-auto')
                    };

                    // hide the items except the first 3
                    $wrapper.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );

                    // the items will have position absolute 
                    // calculate the left of each item
                    $items.each(function(i) {
                        $(this).css({
                            position: 'absolute',
                            left: i * cache.itemW + 'px'
                        });
                    });
                    // click to open the item(s)
                    controls.more.on(evt_ns.click, function( event ) {
                        aux.stopAuto( cache );
                        var $item = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.openItem( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        return false;
                    });
                    // click to close the item(s)
                    controls.close.on(evt_ns.click, function( event ) {
                        aux.stopAuto( cache );
                        var $item = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.closeItems( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        return false;
                    });
                    // navigate left
                    controls.navPrev.on(evt_ns.click, function( event ) {
                        if ( !aux.stopAuto( cache ) ) {
                            if (event.ctrlKey) aux.startAuto( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                            else aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                    // navigate right
                    controls.navNext.on(evt_ns.click, function( event ) {
                        if ( !aux.stopAuto( cache ) ) {
                            if (event.ctrlKey) aux.startAuto( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                            else aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                    // add event handler to the mousewheel
                    $el.on(evt_ns.mousewheel, function( event, delta ) {
                        if (!aux.stopAuto( cache )) {
                            aux.navigate( (delta > 0) ? -1 : 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache);
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                    // add event handler to an optional "auto" button
                    controls.auto.on(evt_ns.click, function( event ) {
                        aux.startAuto(1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache);
                        return false;
                    });
                    // autoStart
                    if(settings.autoStart) {
                        $(window).on('load', function() {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                aux.startAuto(1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache);
                            }, 1000);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    $.fn[pluginName] = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.' + pluginName );
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I don't know for certain what fixed it, but probably the later version of jQuery. Many things improved at 1.7, then progressively at 1.8 and 1.9.

In addition to fixing the Chrome issue, there are some goodies in there for you :

- to start autoScroll on page load, initialise with option `autoStart: true` (default is `false`).
- optionally include an "auto" button (like "more" and "close") to start autoScroll.
- click "prev", "next", "more" or "close" controls to stop autoScroll.
- control-click "prev" or "next" control to start autoScroll.

Only control-click "prev" autoScrolls left. All other autoScrolls go right.

Sample initialization :

```
$(function() {
    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel({
        autoStart: true
    });
});
```

Make sure you test everything before deploying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately the new code is the same with Chrome (just scroll once), but works good with IE and Firefox. It's strange indeed, I don't know what more to do :/ I added a link in my first post with a temporary link to a test page with the slider and the codes if it helps.

Comment: Paulo, see if my Edit helps.

Comment: Dear friend, I just have one thing to say: a big thank you! I spent days and couldn't figure a solution. Now it works great with your revision of the code, I'm testing and till now everything is good in every browser. Thanks for your hard work and kindness, everything is better than I could ask for. I will follow your tips and add a start/play button and some final tyding of the CSS and testing before deploying. But better than this help was impossible. Kind regards and thanks for everything dear friend!

Comment: No worries Paulo, it was fun. Let me know if you find any bugs.

Comment: Its a deal :) But I have been testing and till now everything is great. Thanks for all!